# Multiplatform game, save game state and resume it on other platform

Tags: android, mobile, savegame, cross-platform, web

This is for a personal and knowledge acquiring project.

I want to create a little TIC-TAC-TOE multiplatform game, app & web. The choosen technology for the app will be Android or Flutter and for the web Angular.

My doubt is, during a game if the user wants to change from the mobile version to the web version, how to resume or change the game to the web application? What would be the best way to save the game state and load it into the other platform? Having in consideration that the user will play only in one platform at a time, which is the best way to implement this restriction too?

Is this as simple and hard at the same time as implementing all controls in both platforms and storing all the data required in the database?

Answer (score 1):

If your game requires a server anyway, then the most platform-independent method is indeed to store savegames server-sided and use accounts with passwords to synchronize savegames between devices owned by the same person. Accessing the savegames on the server could be done via a webservice.

Comment: it requires a server anyway, but with a simple webservice I should achieve the requirements throw simple api calls constantly updating the database or is there a better way?

Comment: @notarealgreal Doesn't that fulfill your requirements? What exactly would you expect a "better way" to do better than that solution?